# R/Tesseract for multiple columns: How can I recognize different parts of a text?

Tags: r, ocr, multiple-columns, tesseract

I have scans of some thousand pages of an old swiss computer magazine and am going to make it public as a part of my Masters Thesis. But first I want to do an OCR with R/Tesseract on all the pages and then maybe play around with quanteda.

At this point, I am running a loop that converts the pages to pdf and png, reads ocr and creats a txt file from it. This works pretty well and all the files are converted.

However, as I'm working with a magazine all the pages are structured differently. I have advertising, single columns multiple columns, etc. I cannot make Tesseract recognize the columns and even if it gives me the parting lines (which it does sometimes) I cannot figure out how to structure it the right way.

[image: This is from "Micro & Kleincomputer" (1968/4/p87)]

I'm using this for the OCR:

```
file <-  images_test %>%
   image_convert(type = 'Grayscale') %>%
   image_write(format = 'png')
   text <- tesseract::ocr(file, engine = tesseract("deu"))
   write(text, file = txtpfad)
```

And my results look like this:

> RUND UM DEN IBM-PC 2 IN Ir ne Bytes pro Sektor. Mit der Datenüber- Gruppe von schnellen Arbeitsplatz- estate von 250 Kbits/Sekunde ISSCO
> Software rechnern besteht eine separate können die 10 MB in acht
> Minuten f d DE Be Sr aufgezeichnet oder rückgelesen wer- nfo: ultitec
> : an . (streaming mode/Einmaldurch- au em neuen Bar 66, 3000 Bern 22,
> Tel. 4 lauf). Die drei weiteren Modelle des C . Produktprogrammes
> (Irwin 120, 125 IBM RT P und 325) haben pro Datenkassette .. = sogar
> eine Kapazität von 20 MB. Die erhältlich einzelnen Einheiten
> unterscheiden AT A a l sich jeweils in der Uebertragungsge- von pica
> schwindigkeit, der Gerätegrösse und Die Freigabe der 32-Bit Work- in
> der Art des Aufbaus (Einbau- oder | station von IBM (amerikanische Die
> Personal Computer der AT Peripherie-Gerät) Bezeichnung: IBM RT PC)
> erfolg- | Serie von APICAL erfüllen alle Die beiden Einbaumodelle
> (Irwin | te erst kürzlich. Schon meldet | Anforderungen, die heute an
> ei- 120 und 125) werden wiederum di- | MULTITEC, dass die auf Gross- |
> nen IBM-AT Kompatiblen gestellt rekt an den im PC eingebauten Flop- |
> rechnern und Minicomputern | werden. Und mehr. Sie sind nicht
> py-Kontroller angeschlossen. Da die | verbreiteten Grafik-Software- |
> nur kompatibel, sondern, wie Datentransferrate dieser beiden Ge- |
> Pakete DISSPLA, TELL-A-GRAF, | es sich für einen Rechner der räte bei
> 500 Kbits/Sekunde liegt, | TELLAPLAN und CUECHART | Spitzenklasse
> gehört, obendrein werden die 20 MB in nur knapp neun | jetzt auch auf
> (...)

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution. Tesseract has A LOT of options I have never heard of before. You have to set up your engine the right way first.

```
deu <- tesseract(language = "deu", options = list(tessedit_pageseg_mode = 1))
text <- ocr(file,engine = deu)
```

There is still a potential for improvement but it looks a lot better now.