# R tesseract output is encoded in ANSI, instead of UTF-8

Tags: r, encoding, tesseract

I am a beginner, so my question might not be formulated properly, but my problem is the following:

I am using R tesseract to extract text from PDFs. My source files contains text in multiple columns, therefore I am using a code based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63880625/r-tesseract-for-multiple-columns-how-can-i-recognize-different-parts-of-a-text) and than I write it into a txt file. .

```
eng <- tesseract(language = "eng", options = list(tessedit_pageseg_mode = 1))
text <- ocr("example.pdf",engine = eng)

writeLines(text,con="example.txt")
```

To ensure compatibility and coherence with my other files used for the project, I would like to obtain the result in an UTF-8 encoded file, however, the result is encoded in ANSI. I have been reading about this problem for a few days, but I cannot figure out where is the problem: UTF-8 encoding [is written into R tesseract](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tesseract/tesseract.pdf) and it should not produce results in anything else. The problem is similar to what had been discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/g/tesseract-ocr/c/Mkoh2U3AShU) without any solution.

How I identified that it is in ANSI? - When I open it with notepad, it shows the encoding. Moreover, function "Encoding" returns "unknown"

I am running the latest version of R tesseract with the latest version of R and entering the functions through RStudio on Windows 10.

The encoding problem persist after reboots and regardless of the source file.

Comment: Could you post some examples of strings where the encoding differs?  ANSI and UTF-8 agree for character values less than 128.

Comment: Your link "is written into R tesseract" is unclear.  Do you mean the Encoding line on the first page?  That just says that the source and documentation of the package use UTF-8, it doesn't say it always produces that.

Comment: #2 Oh, thank you, I misunderstood it.

Comment: #1 I am not sure: the texts are in English, however, as I believe that there might be other characters as well in the documents and I wanted to make sure that the texts are correctly rendered. However, I am now sure: if I apply the English engine of the tesseract, it would only recognize the characters of that language (therefore UTF-8 would not provide any advantage?)

Comment: I don't know `tesseract` enough to know.  There are a few non-ASCII characters in English, though they are not used much anymore (e.g. café, often spelled cafe nowadays).  There are also non-ascii symbols like the dagger, double dagger, currency symbols like cents, euros, pounds, yen, etc.

Comment: thank you! then my concerns are probably unfounded :)